# How to plot a smooth 2D color plot for z = f(x, y)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot **2D field data** using matplotlib. So basically I want something similar to this:

[image]

In my actual case I have data stored in a file on my harddrive. However for simplicity consider the function z = f(x, y). I want a smooth 2D plot where z is visualised using color. I managed the plotting with the following lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
z = np.array([i*i+j*j for j in y for i in x])

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = z.reshape(21, 21)

plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

However, the plot I obtain is very coarse. Is there a very simple way to smooth the plot? I know something similar is possible with `surface` plots, however, those are 3D. I could change the camera angle to obtain a 2D representation, but I am convinced there is an easier way. I also tried `imshow` but then I have to think in `graphic` coordinates where the origin is in the upper left corner.

**Problem solved**

I managed to solve my problem using:

`plt.imshow(Z,origin='lower',interpolation='bilinear')`

Comment: The only thing that separates the linked plot with yours is that your grid is much coarser.  Change 21 to something larger, say 101, or 1001.

Comment: Yes I know, but even with a low number of grid points a smooth plot can be obtained using interpolation. `imshow` has that ability. Can I do something similar with `pcolor`?

Comment: Please edit your question to describe _exactly_ what you want, with a representative example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you can't change your mesh granularity, then try to go with `imshow`, which will essentially plot any 2D matrix as an image, where the values of each matrix cell represent the color to make that pixel. Using your example values:

```
In [3]: x = y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 21)
In [4]: z = np.array([i*i+j*j for j in y for i in x])
In [5]: Z = z.reshape(21, 21)
In [7]: plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='bilinear')
Out[7]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f4864277650>
In [8]: plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I am aware of that. But the case I presented was a simple one. I actually have data stored in a `txt` file so I cannot adjust the data. So yes, in a simple function case I could do that. But what do you do in case of data obtained from a 3rd party?

Comment: Thanks I came to this too just now. I also added `origin='lower'`  as a parameter to have the origin at the lower left corner.

Answer (score 13):

you can use `contourf`

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

For more levels (smoother colour transitions), you can use more levels (contours)

For example:

```
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, 100)
```

[image]

Comment: This has clear separation between regions. I want a smooth gradient

Comment: you can increase the number of levels. I'll update with instructions

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `pcolor` or [`pcolormesh`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolormesh.html) if you provide an option to use Gouraud shading:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

y, x = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 5), np.linspace(-1, 1, 5))
z = x**2+y**2
_, [ax1, ax2] = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax1.pcolormesh(x, y, z)
ax1.set_title("Default shading")
ax2.pcolormesh(x, y, z, shading='gouraud')
ax2.set_title("Gouraud shaing")
```

[image: output of commands above. Plot with and without gouraud shading]